# Achieve a patterned and blurry effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

I'm looking to create an effect similar to this patterned logo and blurry? also, I'm trying to blur half of the shape but in all the blur effects in Illustrator, I could find only blur the whole element.

please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very likely looking at output from plugins.

Comment: Why do you think these were done via Illustrator? In all probability they were created with a raster editor, and may even be stills from video. You *might* be able to achieve something similar in AI, but the reality is you would need to **carefully** plan any "blurring" and fake it via meshes. There would be no "easy" method in AI.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how I'd best approach that in Illustrator - I know I could achieve that in Affinity Designer without having to rasterise any layers by using adjustment layers with masks... you could therefore accomplish the same final result with two Adobe apps: Illustrator for the prime work then Photoshop for the adjustments.

I was wrong - at least *here at my client's site* where their ITS group is... ***not*** fast... *they're* still rocking Affinity version 1.6.3 - but I *can* open my Affinity Designer file in Affinity Photo (all the same file type under the hood) add my Gaussian Blur adjustment layer, paint a mask, then reopen the same file in Affinity Designer - all my vector line work is still there as sheer editable vector goodness.

[image]

So the Affinity version of this workflow allows bi-directionality and nondestructive editing - I bet you could achieve a similar thing, albeit one-directional, with Illustrator & Photoshop by placing your Illustrator artwork as a Smart Object - in fact I know you can! Sadly, this ***won't*** get you the ability to *push changes back and forth* between apps, but you'll keep your vector editability in the `.ai` file, *and* be able to apply your creative filtering in Photoshop.

Oh, and of course you can take the same approach with the various distortion filters - mask paint and change impact - all without touching the underlying vector art - I added a ripple distortion layer for good measure.

[image]

---

OK - on reviewing my own answer, I see it's not super-clear from the images I posted how close to the OP's samples the approach I suggested was getting, so I took 3 minutes in Affinity Designer & Affinity Photo to make this, to show that this approach can get exactly what the OP's asking for:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The stripes seem to be repeated copies of the letters which are squeezed horizontally, rotated and even warped to have a little twist.The stripe pattern has been used as opacity mask for text., which has been blurred in a complex way. It can contain several versions together. The final result also has blur but that can be a consequence of low pixel resolution.

This all is of course only guesses until they are proven by making something resembling. I'll return to it later.